# Who are the hidden team members on the GTA Online: The Diamond Casino Heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

On the new casino heist, there are some team members that appear with a "hidden" icon and can't be selected. Who are the hidden members? How can I unlock them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden/unlockable crew members are:

### Gunmans

#### Charlie Reed

Requires purchase of a Hangar.

#### Chester McCoy

Requires purchase of a Bunker or Arena Workshop.

#### Patrick McReary

Requires completion of freemode event, where you steal a police vehicle with Packie on the back and drop him in the designated location after losing the cops.

---

### Drivers

#### Zach Nelson

Requires purchase of the MC Clubhouse.

#### Chester McCoy

Requires purchase of a Bunker or Arena Workshop.

---

### Hackers

#### Yohan Blair

Requires purchase of the Nightclub.

#### Paige Harris

Requires purchase of the Terrorbyte.

#### Avi Schwartzman

Requires the destruction of all 50 Signal Jammers around the map.